# Strange behavior of identity column in Db2?

Tags: db2

I have created a dummy table in Db2 using an identity column. DDL of which is shared below:

```
CREATE TABLE new_employees (
sl_no int, 
ident smallint generated always as identity
    (start with 1,
    increment by 1,
    minvalue 1)
);
```

However, when I am inserting data, instead of the identity column populating with 1 incremented by 1 it is getting inserted in an (to me) abnormal way. Why is it happening?

[image]

Comment: How you are inserting this data?

Comment: insert into new_employees(sl_no) values (5); This is a sample statement of insertion

Comment: @Somanka see below

Answer (score 4):

The reason is the caching of sequences / identity values. I assume you have done the following:
 - your database has not been activated
 - you are connected and deconnected from Db2 for the tests

Db2 fills up a cache of values for each sequence / identity whenever it is used the first time. From there it consumes the values. Whenever the Db2 database shuts down (last connection terminated or database deactivated), the remaining numbers in the cache are lost.
The default cache size is 20, see [CREATE TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html) or CREATE SEQUENCE. There is a NO CACHE option.

Comment: note that while `NO CACHE` would solve the missing sequence number issue, there is a performance penalty to pay for it.  Particularly in a production scenario where multiple processes are making inserts.